# Is there a more efficient way to resize a two-dimensional grid represented as a Vec<T>?

Tags: vector, memory-management, rust

I have a struct containing a two-dimensional grid represented by a single `Vec<u8>` because `wasm_bindgen` does not support `<Vec<Vec<T>>`. For example, the grid:

```
0 1 
2 3
```

is stored as a `Vec<u8>` with elements `[0, 1, 2, 3]` ([row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)).

I want to be able to resize the grid's width; if the new width is smaller the grid should remove columns from the right, if the new width is larger the grid should fill new columns with zeros. Items may have to be added or removed at multiple locations within the `Vec`.

To set the grid's width I am chunking the `Vec`, turning the chunks into vectors, resizing the vectors, and flattening the vectors.

```
struct Matrix {
    grid: Vec<u8>,
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
}

impl Matrix {
    pub fn set_width(&mut self, new_width: usize) {
        self.grid = self
            .grid
            .chunks_exact(self.width)
            .flat_map(|chunk| {
                let mut chunk_vec = chunk.to_vec();
                chunk_vec.resize(new_width, 0);
                chunk_vec
            })
            .collect();

        self.width = new_width;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I think the chunks are probably allocating a lot of memory on large grid sizes as they all get turned into `Vec`s.

---

Setting the height is much easier as the `Vec` will only need to be extended or truncated:

```
pub fn set_height(&mut self, new_height: usize) {
    self.grid.resize(self.width * new_height, 0);
    self.height = new_height;
}
```

Comment: *I want to be able to resize the grid's width* — do you also want to resize the height? [Row- and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

Comment: An alternative would be to use an n-dimensional array library. For example: https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/

Comment: @Shepmaster I can resize the height right now with `self.grid.resize(self.width * new_height, 0)` to add or remove rows from the end of the `Vec`. Thanks for the article I'll have to read more about the topic!

Comment: If you can change to a [strided array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937854/5397009), then decreasing the width can be done in O(1) (and increasing it back to the old width or less is also O(1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply reduce the number of allocations, you can make the closure passed to `flat_map` return an iterator instead of a `Vec`:

```
pub fn set_width(&mut self, new_width: usize) {
    use std::iter::repeat;
    self.grid = self
        .grid
        .chunks_exact(self.width)
        .flat_map(|chunk| chunk.iter().copied().chain(repeat(0)).take(new_width))
        .collect();

    self.width = new_width;
}
```

That is, for each chunk, create an iterator that yields the `copied` contents of the chunk followed by a `repeat`ed string of 0s, and truncate it (`take`) to total size `new_width`. This does not require creating any `Vec`s to store intermediate results and so it allocates less... most likely.

This is okay, but it could be better. `FlatMap` can't know the size of the internal iterators, so it doesn't give a useful `size_hint` (see [Efficiency of flattening and collecting slices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58571612/3650362) for a similar example). This means the `Vec` in the solution above starts empty and may have to be grown (reallocated and its contents copied) several times before it is large enough. Instead, we can use `Vec::with_capacity` first to reserve the correct amount of space, and `extend` the vector instead of `collect`ing into it:

```
pub fn set_width(&mut self, new_width: usize) {
    use std::iter::repeat;
    let mut new_grid = Vec::with_capacity(self.grid.len() / self.width * new_width);
    for chunk in self.grid.chunks_exact(self.width) {
        new_grid.extend(chunk.iter().copied().chain(repeat(0)).take(new_width));
    }
    self.grid = new_grid;

    self.width = new_width;
}
```

It is also possible to resize the grid in-place, with at most one reallocation (often reusing the existing one). However, that algorithm is significantly more complicated. The above is how I would write `set_width` unless it were proven to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Is the order of the grid points relevant for you? If not, I would use a different serialization from 2D to 1D:

Given you have a matrix like this:

```
1 2 5
3 4 6
7 8 9
```

So you if the matrix gets wider or higher you don't move the indices of the smaller positions at all, but just append the new entries as new “layers” around the matrix you already have.

You could serialize this to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Assuming all indices, and coordinates start at `0`:
Given you want to access (n, m) you find the “layer” the matrix value is in by calculating `max(n, m)`. The n-th “layer” will start at index position `n * n`. Within the layer you find the first `n` elements in the part added on the right side, and the following `n+1` elements in the row added on the bottom.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but it only supports square (or approximately square) matrices, right?

Comment: @trentcl If it's not exactly square you could just keep height and width in separate variables and ignore the indices you don't need. If the matrix is very asymmetric you probably modify the way you serialize to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Gave a shot at resizing the grid's width in-place, only reserving new memory once when `new_width` > `self.width`:

```
use std::{cmp::Ordering, iter};

pub fn set_width(&mut self, new_width: usize) {
    match new_width.cmp(&self.width) {
        Ordering::Greater => {
            let width_diff = new_width - self.width;
            self.grid.reserve_exact(width_diff * self.height);

            for _ in 0..self.height {
                self.grid.extend(iter::repeat(0).take(width_diff));
                self.grid.rotate_right(new_width);
            }
        }

        Ordering::Less => {
            let width_diff = self.width - new_width;

            for _ in 0..self.height {
                self.grid.truncate(self.grid.len() - width_diff);
                self.grid.rotate_right(new_width);
            }
        }

        Ordering::Equal => (),
    }

    self.width = new_width;
}
```

I was considering iterating over the `Vec`'s reversed rows and using `splice` to insert/remove values, but I'm not sure if it's any more efficient.

Using `splice`:

```
use std::{cmp::Ordering, iter};

pub fn set_width(&mut self, new_width: usize) {
    match new_width.cmp(&self.width) {
        Ordering::Greater => {
            let width_diff = new_width - self.width;
            let width = self.width;
            self.grid.reserve_exact(width_diff * self.height);

            for i in (0..self.height).rev().map(|n| n * width + width) {
                self.grid.splice(i..i, iter::repeat(0).take(width_diff));
            }
        }

        Ordering::Less => {
            let width_diff = self.width - new_width;
            let width = self.width;
            for (start, end) in (1..=self.height)
                .rev()
                .map(|n| (n * width - width_diff, n * width))
            {
                self.grid.splice(start..end, iter::empty());
            }
        }

        Ordering::Equal => (),
    }

    self.width = new_width;
}
```