# How to remove a column from a matrix defined as Vectors within a Map in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a matrix defined in C++ using vectors within a map as the following:

```
typedef std::vector<double> MyVector;
typedef std::map<unsigned int,MyVector> MyMap;
```

The vectors have number of elements equal to the number of keys in the map. So, without counting the column holding the keys, the collection of vectors will represent n*n matrix.
If I want to remove a row, then I can just use "map.erase(key)" to do that.
However, I don't have a way to remove a specific column from this matrix.

Comment: You could iterate on all the rows, and delete the relevant entry for the column you want to remove. But are you sure you have good reasons to use this representation ? Matrices are usually represented with a continuous block of memory, and a `stride` parameter to determine the distance in memory between rows.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, that is what I was thinking about, but do you have another version of the inner for loop for the vector 
    for (auto j=mMap.begin();j != mMap.end(); ++j){
        for (auto vector : j->second){
            cout<<vector<<", ";
        }
          cout<<endl;  
    }

Comment: @wohlstad I picked this representation because the size of my matrix is not fixed. So when I rebulid the matrix, I just clear the map and fill it with the new values. In terms of your block of memory suggestion, could you please give me a example of it can help me? thanks

Comment: I don't think using a continous block of memory will help your specific issue. But is has other advantages, you can see here and consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937169/what-is-a-strided-array.

Comment: @wohlstad nice concept, thank you for introducing it to me. However, as I mentioned before my matrix has no fixed size. Map and Vector allow me to push_back values without specifying the size initially. If I presented my matrix as a long vector, can I use the stride concept ?

Comment: If you want a resizeable matrix (or any-dimensional array) then contiguous data is a really good solution, and you can effectively wrap `std::vector`, but there should be a library to save you the work. Consider [boost::multi_array](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). I think it's resizable, but haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is to remove the row and corresponding column based on the map's key. It is not perfect and I wish if someone improve upon it.

```
MyMap a2d;
MyMapIterator itr;
double value=1;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    a2d[i].emplace_back(value);
    a2d[i].emplace_back(value);
    a2d[i].emplace_back(value);
    a2d[i].emplace_back(value);
    a2d[i].emplace_back(value);
    value++;
}

//display the Array
for (itr=a2d.begin();itr!= a2d.end();itr++){
    for (auto vitr=itr->second.begin();vitr!=itr->second.end();vitr++){
        cout<<*vitr<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;

double rowR=2; // the map's key which represent the index of the row to be removed
double columnR;
columnR=distance(a2d.begin(),a2d.find(rowR)); //the amount of increment should be added to the vector's iterator to remove the required column
a2d.erase(rowR); // removing the 3rd row 

for (itr=a2d.begin();itr!= a2d.end();itr++){
    auto &k=itr->second;
    k.erase(k.begin()+columnR); // removing the 3rd column 
}
// re-displaying the array after change 
for (itr=a2d.begin();itr!= a2d.end();itr++){
    for (auto vitr=itr->second.begin();vitr!=itr->second.end();vitr++){
        cout<<*vitr<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```